# show SKU in Product view only from simple products

Tags: product, filter, sku, view

I think its easy but i don't found a way. In the product view.phtml ,I want to show the SKU. But only for simple Products. Is there any Way like this:

```
<div class="product-sku">
<h3>
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product,$_product->getSku()->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple'), 'sku') ?>
</h3>
</div>
```

This way don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
<?php if($_product->getTypeId() == 'simple'): ?>

<div class="product-sku">
  <h3><?php echo $_product->getSku()?></h3>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```